# How to display SQL query results in one line?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am going out of my mind trying to get this to work and here it is, I have 3 tables. I think it's much better to show you the tables are "tblhosting", "tblhostingconfigoptions" and "tblcustomfieldsvalues" It can be seen here in the SQLFiddle setup: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c153/1

What I am trying to accomplish is making it in one line, see picture:
[image]

Below is my SQL query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
t1.domainstatus,
t1.server,
t1.dedicatedip,
t1.packageid,
t1.regdate,
t1.nextduedate,
t2.value,
t2.fieldid,
t3.configid,
t3.qty
FROM tblhosting t1
INNER JOIN tblcustomfieldsvalues t2 
ON t2.relid = t1.id 
INNER JOIN tblhostingconfigoptions t3 
ON t3.relid = t1.id
WHERE t3.configid IN (126,127,128) AND t2.fieldid IN
(83,84,85,86,87,88,90,91,92,93,208) ORDER by t1.id -- I use to have GROUP by t1.id and get 1 line for the 126 but then 127 128 will not be produced.
```

I'll isolate the `<td>` to just the problem, it's all inside this PHP code:

```php
$sql = mysql_query($queryText);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

  $qty = $row['qty'];
  $configid = $row['configid'];

  echo '<td id="sid">' . $row['value'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td id="smip">' . $dedicatedIP . '</td>';
  echo '<td id="10g">'; if ($configid == 126) { echo '4' } echo'</td>'; // the qty matching 126 should display there
  echo '<td id="40g">'; if ($configid == 127) { echo '0'} echo'</td>'; // the qty matching 127 should display there 
  echo '<td id="100g">'; if ($configid == 128) { echo '0' } echo'</td>'; // the qty matching 128 should display there
```

.... The idea above is to make the `$configid` match 126 or 127 or 128, and output into the field the row `qty` accordingly which is 4 0 0 and not output 3 times the "ded13526" and put 4 then next line 0 then next line 0.

Hope it comes off with enough explanation, I didn't want to post the entire code to confuse, it's obvious the `IN` statement has 80 to 93 then 208 and this exact entry is only 93..

I just don't know what is wrong..

Comment: in the output (while loop), keep track of the values, dont echo duplicates

Comment: Your syntax in the code that is supposed to emit the table row is completely broken.

Comment: Hobo Sapiens, what do you mean broken. Trust me i have been trying to solve this mystery for a long time. I just gave you the chunks that are relevant, the entire code is a bit different. I know this is something simple but I am not getting it, any help is appreciated what in the PHP and SQL code would need to be altered to be able to put the values in the fields next to each other and not echo 3 lines because of 126 127 128

Comment: Dagon, Ill update the output to just remove it so that it wont confuse, lets just add it like this.

Comment: use `group by` in your sql query for common fields. For example You have a Field `fieldid` have same value, which shows duplicate records in table, so add `group by fieldid` in your query.
I think this will solve your problem, what i understood.

Comment: @HP's411 I use to have Group by t1.id that would produce one line with 126 but hide 127 128 and you say fieldid has same value? what do you mean it has a value 93 so you mean instead of "order by t1.id" do it "group by t2.fieldid"? 

UPDATE: I did that
WHERE t3.configid IN (126,127,128) AND t2.fieldid IN (83,84,85,86,87,88,90,91,92,93,208) GROUP by t2.fieldid

Produced only 10 sets of results totally random, I don't think i can group by fieldid, the fieldid is 93 in this case

Comment: @SteiniPetur : I mean to say, the FIELD which holds track of Duplicate records, you need to assign that field in GROUP BY i had gave you an Example only.

Comment: @HP's411 see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c153/2 with the group by t2.fieldid it did group it but I've lost 127 128 with this method, so basically Im back to square one :/.... UPDATE: I understand that, but the moment i group it by a common field that produces the dublicates it removes the dublicates but hides 127 128 so I can't get those values anymore I use to use "Group by t1.id" that would get rid of all the dublicates and now I can't get the values in t3.configid only the 126 if i try to get the 127 128 i get nothing

Comment: @HP's411 Keep in mind, I always thought I didn't have to display them all. I thought that if i join the tables by relid and id so they are now 1 table I could do something like this 

if $row['configid'] == 126 do this else if configid == 127 and so forth but only 126 is fetched the 127 is totally empty? but I can fetch other values like 33 from the database.. Is it because of the "IN (126,127,128)" ?? What is causing 127 128 to be EMPTY while 126 and even 33 and 58 from the same table pump out information no problem

Comment: @SteiniPetur : in your database there one field which connect to those all table, which field is that?? If there is not any field like this, than i think you must have to go with php code for your required output.

Comment: @SteiniPetur : i am searching for that fields in your fiddle, some fields are not giving required output, and which gives are not help for the required Output.

Comment: @HP's411 You can see that tblhosting has an id of 1240, that relates to the tblhostingconfigoptions relid of 1240 as well as tblcustomfieldsvalues relid of 1240 .. This is the common value, it's the very user id in tblhosting relating to relid in both configoptions and customfieldsvalues.. I have joined 2 tables easy but now with the 3rd one, this is why i do Group by t1.id since that is 1240 and limits the display to 1 line. Then I wanted to just use PHP to GET the values in the 3rd table t3.configid and check that value is it 126, then do this etc

Comment: @SteiniPetur : It will not give us required output, i have tested it before.

Comment: @SteiniPetur : I think you should have to move with PHP for your Output. in this case SQL will not help..

Comment: @HP's411 That is what I am trying to do, the SQL Fiddle is just to show you the table structure and connection, I am aware it will create 3 lines what I don't get is why I cannot for the life of me.. go into t3.configid and locate 126 put A there and if its 127 put B there like this...`<td id="10g">'; if ($configid == 126) { echo 'A'; } echo'</td>
<td id="40g">'; if ($configid == 127) { echo 'B';} echo'</td>
<td id="100g">'; if ($configid == 128) { echo 'C'; } echo'</td>`

Comment: @HP's411 something like this `$resultset = sprintf("
SELECT
t1.domainstatus,
t1.server,
t1.dedicatedip,
t1.packageid,
t1.regdate,
t1.nextduedate,
t2.value,
t2.fieldid,
t3.configid,
t3.qty
FROM tblhosting t1
INNER JOIN tblcustomfieldsvalues t2 
ON t2.relid = t1.id 
INNER JOIN tblhostingconfigoptions t3 
ON t3.relid = t1.id
WHERE t2.fieldid IN (83,84,85,86,87,88,90,91,92,93,208) GROUP by t1.id
");` With this setup, shouldn't I be able to fetch any value that appears in the t3.configid? with this nothing comes out but if i add "AND t3.configid (126,127,128)" I can at least fetch 126?

Comment: @HP's411 Sorry about the constant comments, Just so im clear I appreciate all help I am receiving here and greatful, I don't get it what in my SQL statement doesn't allow me to get values from t3 but I can get t2 values like as you can see in the screenshot im getting t2.fieldid value of 93 no problem but I don't get access to the t3 table unless i add AND t3.configid IN (126,127,128) and then i have access to one of these I can remove 126 and then its 127 if i remove all but 128 then 128 i have access to... Im going nuts here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, here is how it can be solved:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
t1.domainstatus,
t1.server,
t1.dedicatedip,
t1.packageid,
t1.regdate,
t1.nextduedate,
t2.value,
t2.fieldid,
(SELECT qty FROM tblhostingconfigoptions WHERE relid = t1.id AND configid = 126) AS qty126,
(SELECT qty FROM tblhostingconfigoptions WHERE relid = t1.id AND configid = 127) AS qty127,
(SELECT qty FROM tblhostingconfigoptions WHERE relid = t1.id AND configid = 128) AS qty128
FROM tblhosting t1
JOIN tblcustomfieldsvalues t2 ON t2.relid = t1.id 
WHERE t2.fieldid IN (83,84,85,86,87,88,90,91,92,93,208)
```

```php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
  ...
  echo '<td id="sid">' . $row['value'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td id="smip">' . $row['dedicatedip'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td id="10g">' . $row['qty126'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td id="40g">' . $row['qty127'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td id="100g">' . $row['qty128'] . '</td>';
  ...
```

Comment: This is so close, it's getting me the numbers in each but skips a few like returning empty for loads of them but then numbers appear in the other see [link](http://i61.tinypic.com/s6hgjq.png). Basically It is doing what I want it to do but it's not getting all of them, I checked and in "tblhostingconfigoptions" if relid is 3857 which is one of the empties and configid is 126 it does have 0 0 0 in 126 127 128 so it should show up but it doesn't then we have 1240 which has 0 0 0 and shows up just fine... It must be in the SQL something that is restricting. Im tempted to accept the answer

Comment: I can also confirm that one of these empty columns is fieldid

relid
value
91
3558
ded22943

uses fieldid 91 so it's not missing in the "IN ()", something else is causing some of these not to show up. Besides that you have just shown me a method I never knew before and I appreciate it :)

Comment: Sorry, I found the problem there it was that for example 3558 relid does have corresponding 126 127 128 in the tblhostingconfigoptions but for example 1006 relid does not have 126 127 128 in tblhostingconfigoptions. It's just not there so it can't link up using your method :).. The answer is therefor accepted, thank you very much :)

Comment: @SteiniPetur, you are welcome! Also consider [upvoting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) the answer :)

Comment: done, upvoting and accepted. The last piece of the puzzle was somehow that in this WHMCS script I had to goto each product for it to generate an configid 126 127 128 into tblhostingconfigoptions basically, I went manually to the remaining 80+ products and on looking them up configid was made in the database so now it's all working wonders.. all rows full of numbers :).. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
t1.domainstatus,
t1.server,
t1.dedicatedip,
t1.packageid,
t1.regdate,
t1.nextduedate,
t2.value,
t2.fieldid,
t3.configid,
t3.qty
FROM tblhosting t1
INNER JOIN tblcustomfieldsvalues t2 
ON t2.relid = t1.id 
INNER JOIN tblhostingconfigoptions t3 
ON t3.relid = t1.id
WHERE t3.configid IN (126,127,128) AND t2.fieldid IN
(83,84,85,86,87,88,90,91,92,93,208) GROUP BY t2.fieldid
```

Comment: I tried this, with t2.fieldid it gives out about 10 sets random, it works with Group by t1.id to get everything, The issue is apparently not in the SQL but in the PHP, what Im trying to accomplish since we know that t3.configid will always have 3 entries 126 127 128 and if we just group them we get 126 and 127 128 disappear.. I just don't seem to be able to tap into this t3.configid 127 128 to add them to the columns next to each other in the PHP end

Comment: `<td id="10g">'; if ($configid == 126) { echo $qty; } echo'</td>
<td id="40g">'; if ($configid == 127) { echo $qty;} echo'</td>
<td id="100g">'; if ($configid == 128) { echo $qty; } echo'</td>` Why can i get the 126 fine but 127 128 not, they only appear if i remove the GROUP by t1.id and stop grouping and render 3 lines then i can fetch it  but not in a single line